# Missing attributes in SearchResultEntry

Tags: c#, active-directory

We have a small application, which is responsible for reading out data from an active directory. In our local tests the results we got by using a SearchRequest instance seemed to be working well. But now we have a customer, where the attribute 'cn' is missing for no reason (or so we think).

The customers domaincontroller runs on the same OS as we ran our local tests (Windows Server 2016).

Some differences between customer and our testscenario:

- Customer uses port 636, we use 389
- Customer active directory does not run on the same server as our application, ours does.

Our approach looks like the following:

```
 string domainName = "domain";         
 string baseDn = "basedn";
 string adminDN = "CN=ADMINDN";
 string adminPassword = "password";
 int port = 389;
 string userSearchFilter = "(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))";           


//SearchRequest APPROACH
 IList<SearchResultEntryCollection> pagedResults = new List<SearchResultEntryCollection>();
 LdapDirectoryIdentifier ldapDirectoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(domainName, port);
 NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(adminDN, adminPassword);
 LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldapDirectoryIdentifier, networkCredential, AuthType.Basic);

 ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
 ldapConnection.Bind();

 SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
                    (baseDn,
                        userSearchFilter,
                        System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree,
                        null);

 SearchOptionsControl searchOptions = new SearchOptionsControl(System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchOption.DomainScope);
 searchRequest.Controls.Add(searchOptions);

 SearchResponse searchResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

 textBuilder.Clear();

 foreach (SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry in searchResponse.Entries) 
 {
      foreach (DirectoryAttribute directoryAttribute1 in searchResultEntry.Attributes.Values)
      {
           object[] objectArray = directoryAttribute1.GetValues(typeof(byte[]));
           byte[] byteArray = (byte[])objectArray[0];
            textBuilder.AppendLine("UC Attributename:" + directoryAttribute1.Name + " AttributeValue: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray));
      }
  }
  File.WriteAllText(".\\searchRequestlOutput.txt", textBuilder.ToString());
```

To check if the implementation really is the issue here I implemented the same with the PrincipalClass, which looks like this:

```
    string username = "admin";
    string adminPassword = "password";
    string domainName = "domain";        

    StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    //PRINCIPAL APPROACH

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, username, adminPassword))
    {
        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
        {
            foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                textBuilder.AppendLine();

                foreach (string strProperty in de.Properties.PropertyNames)
                {

                    textBuilder.AppendLine(strProperty + ": " + de.Properties[strProperty].Value);
                }
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(".\\principalOutput.txt", textBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

With the principal approach I can read out all attributes, including 'cn' on the customer side. The SearchRequest approach offers no 'cn' and no errors, which we could research further. The dictionary just doesn't offer the 'cn' attribute.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it show up if you specify a list of attributes to retrieve and include `cn`? In the constructor for `SearchRequest`, replace that `null` with an array of strings that includes `cn`. (this is a good idea to do anyway, because then you don't retrieve attributes that you won't use - it will improve performance a bit)

Comment: I found the issue. I don't know why, but it works now. Will write an answer later. It has a lot to do with what you wrote Gabriel. Thanks for that!